# I am not sure what “: command not found” means when I run virtualenvwrapper mkvirtualenv command

Tags: django, ubuntu, virtualenvwrapper

I am learning Linux and how to set-up a Django environment for the first time. 
I am not sure what “: command not found” means when I run virtualenvwrapper commands. Below is the command line sequence:

```
    root@intranet-django:/home/lv/# workon
    root@intranet-django:/home/lv/# mkvirtualenv temp
    Using base prefix ‘/usr’
    New python executable in /root/.virtualenvs/temp/bin/python3
    Also creating executable in /root/.virtualenvs/temp/bin/python
    Installing setuptools, pip, wheel…done
    :command not found
    root@intranet-django:/home/lv/# workon
    temp
    root@intranet-django:/home/lv/#
```

Comment: @SvekarP This is not related, here `mkvirtualenv` is clearly found

Comment: sorry about that, can you give us more info, how did you installed you `virtualenvwrapper` did you installed it with `pip` or `sudo`?

Comment: I will assume you have `python2` and `python3` installed on your local machine, try specify python path for your `virtualenv` like this `$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>`, and see will it work

Comment: @SvekarP, thanks for your help. I installed using PIP. I added the following to .bashrc and .profile:

Comment: `export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs 
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Comment: Glad I can help, try specifying you python3.x path in the future and you will be fine,  happy coding

Comment: @SvekarP, I am receiving an error when running $ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/ from the command line. I am trying to figure out how to copy from the terminal session to post here but not having any luck yet. The gist of the error is "permission denied". Also I do not have a python directory in /usr/local/bin

Comment: OK I think I get it thank you. I run virtualenv -p with the correct path to python3?

Comment: @SvekarP, Thank you. Where do I specify python3.x? My path includes /usr/bin which is where python3x is located. I'm lost.

Comment: Got it: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#quick-start

Comment: export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your `virtualenv` and specify you `python3.x` path by running this command `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin python3.x <project_name>`.

If you want to check your `python3.x` path, you run `which python3.x` in you terminal.